# deep links not working on chrome browser for Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, deep-linking

I am trying to open mobile app when clicking on the link ( web ). I want to open instagram profile.

I tried this

`instagram://user?username=kamal`

It is working on safari browser but not in Chrome browser for IPHONE.

I also tried this one :-

`intent://#Intent;scheme=user?username=Maliamanuel;package=com.instagram.android;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmockup.in/;end"`

But it is not working on any browser.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?